# Nothing happens on composer.phar update

Tags: php, composer-php

Nothing happens when I enter the following line in the terminal:

```
php composer.phar update
```

The same for install or any other option.

What could be the problem? I am working on CentOS. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Usually if *nothing* at all happens it is due to a misconfiguration, and you can check for config problems by running the installer again in check-only mode:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --check
```

Comment: It's generally a good idea, however it might happen that even if the check succeeds, the composer won't work. (As in my case)

Comment: I use windows and I have to do it in CMD. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In case the installer check @Seldaek recommended works fine, **and** you're in a **chroot environment** this should save your ass (it did mine):

Copy `/usr/share/zoneinfo` into the chroot environment as well.

See [this github issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2867#issuecomment-39650282).